# Missing Columns in DataSet when importing from Text File

Tags: c#, data-import

I'm trying to import a pipe-delimited text file into a dataset via C#.  Some of the columns are not importing the headers.

This is my source data:

```
Apple|Orange|Banana|Grape|Mango|Guava|Apricot|Pear|Peach
0C025X0|530335|WEROERWORUWEORWEU||Misc.||0|1|0
```

Here is my code:

```
         bool conversionStatus = true;

         //instantiate new Excel Object
        Application xlApp = new Application();
        _Workbook wb = null;
        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return false;
        }


        //OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "; Extended Properties = \"text;HDR=No;FMT=TabDelimited\"");
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + "; Extended Properties = \"text;HDR=No\"");
        conn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(filePath), conn);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Temp");
        adapter.Fill(ds);
```

My formatting is being set in a schema.ini file which looks like this:

```
[Master.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=False
```

The following is how the data looks in the dataset.

[image]

Does anyone know why some headers are being included, while others are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your situation and I have solved it changing the `schema.ini` file to

```
[Master.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=Name1 Text Width 100
Col2=Name2 Text Width 100
Col3=Name3 Text Width 100
Col4=Name4 Text Width 100
Col5=Name5 Text Width 100
Col6=Name6 Text Width 100
Col7=Name7 Text Width 100
Col8=Name8 Text Width 100
Col9=Name9 Text Width 100
```

Setting the column list with a sample `name and type` seems to fix the problem.

After a bit of research I noticed the fact that the missing values are from columns that have values of conflicting type.

For example, the column F2 should contain the word ORANGE in the first line, but the following line contains a number and the same happens in all the other columns with the missing values. So I think that the Text Driver has decided to give a numeric type to the columns and, of course, cannot represent string values in that column.
Now to check this theory I have added these lines to your code:

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns["F2"].DataType);  // prints Int32
```

Bingo. The driver has choosen the DataType Int32 for the column F2 and the word ORANGE cannot be shown there.

To fix it then you could add to your schema.ini the column names with their datatype to avoid ambiguity between the actual column values.